# Tabu Search Algorithm always crashing on the second iteration

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, malloc

```
typedef struct{
    int *sols;
    int rest;
    int fitness;
    int num;
    struct lista* next;
}lista;

lista* gere_lista(lista *solucoes, int *sol, int *grafo, int objs, int rests){
    int i;
    int *nova_sol;
    lista *temp = solucoes;
    nova_sol = malloc(sizeof(int)*objs);
    nova_sol = update_sol(sol, nova_sol, objs);
    for(i=0; i<objs; i++){
        nova_sol = gera_vizinho3(nova_sol, i);
        temp->sols = malloc(sizeof(int)*objs);
        temp->sols = update_sol(nova_sol, temp->sols, objs);
        temp->rest = calcula_restricoes(nova_sol, grafo, objs, rests);
        temp->fitness = calcula_max(nova_sol, grafo, objs);
        temp->num = i;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return solucoes;
}

int* pesquisa_tabu(int sol[], int *grafo, int objs, int rests, int num_iter){
    int fitness, fitness_viz, i, memoria[objs*2/8];
    lista *solucoes, *temp;

    solucoes = malloc(sizeof(lista));
    temp = solucoes;

    for(i=1; i<objs; i++){
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(lista));
    }
    temp->next = NULL;
    solucoes = gere_lista(solucoes, sol, grafo, objs, rests);
    return sol;
}
```

I'm trying to do a tabu search algorithm to my school assignment, but it's not really working.
This code is supposed to create a linked list with the same number of links as the objects that are in the pesquisa_tabu function, then it generates the same number in neighbors and add one neighbor to each link, to then process all the information in the pesquisa_tabu function.
And i can't find what is wrong in this code, it is always crashing on the second iteration...

Comment: Your for-loop is wrong, you are just allocating memory to the same temp->next over and over, and then set it to null right after

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for(i=1; i<objs; i++){
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(lista));
    }
    temp->next = NULL;
```

What you have done is allocated memory for `objs` number of `lista`'s and lost links to all of them because you are always making `temp->next` point to a new memory and then later making it point to `NULL`.You need to maintain a `head` of the list while allocating memory for all nodes.

```
lista *solucoes, *temp;//solucoes will act as head of list    
temp = NULL;
solucoes = NULL;

for(i=1; i<objs; i++)
{
    if(solucoes==NULL)
    {
         temp = malloc(sizeof(lista));
         solucoes = temp;
    }
    else    
    {
        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(lista));
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
temp->next = NULL;
```

Comment: I'm using `temp` as a temporary pointer, the main pointer is `solucoes` , will i lose all links even if i use a temporary pointer?